# How to show fields below checkbox based on "checked" in Redux Framework?

Tags: wordpress, checkbox, redux-framework

I've downloaded the Redux Framework (using generator). I want some fields to be displayed if a checkbox field is checked (more related fields below checkbox).

I searched online and found some Redux code having `checkbox_hide_below` field which is not present in the current Redux Framework.

Will I have to do it all by myself or Redux framework provides some option to show/hide fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lead dev of Redux here.

You'd have to do it yourself, however it's really pretty easy.

First, you'd do a get_option to your opt_name before you run your config. Then on the fields you want to make hidden you'd do something like this:

```
$options = get_options('OPT_NAME');
$field = array(
    'id'       => 'textarea_id',
    'type'     => 'textarea',
    'hidden'   => ( $options['test_value'] == 1 ) ? true : false,
    'title'    => __( 'Test Hidden Field', 'redux-framework-demo' ),
    'desc'     => __( 'This field will be set to be hidden if text_value is 1.', 'redux-framework-demo' ),
);
```

It's pretty strait forward. I hope that helps! You can also apply the hidden argument to sections as well.  ;)

Comment: How can we do it on client side? using jQuery?

Comment: Oh, dynamic JS? Then you'd use this doc: http://docs.reduxframework.com/core/advanced/custom-panel-css/

Instead of CSS you enqueue JS and do your own jQuery magic.  ;)

Comment: 'hidden' doesn't seem to work. Is there some other property to do that?

Comment: Are you adding hidden to the field via jQuery? That of course will not work. Try making a field hidden via PHP and see where the classes are added.  ;)

Comment: I did set 'hidden'   => true in PHP but it didn't add any classes neither did it hide the field.

Comment: This issue is better served on our issue tracker. The code is there and the docs outline it. Look through some issues, maybe you'll find your answer. https://github.com/ReduxFramework/redux-framework/issues